# My textures are being mirrored. Also, how do I get the textures to be 3D?

Tags: texturing

I'm new to Blender. I created this respiratory model but I'm having issues with the textures being mirrored and stretched. Furthermore, the textures are 3D but they are not 3D on my model. I would sincerely appreciate anyone who could help me with this. Also, if anyone could recommend free textures that look similar to tissue I would appreciate that sincerely as well. If anyone else has any suggestions to improve this model I would also appreciate that! Thank you for your assistance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a procedural texture for the skin, if you want to use an existing image, you can first apply the *Array* modifier if you have some, then unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* mode, in the *Shader Editor* create a new material, plug a new *Image Texture* (with a new image) into the *Principled BSDF*, switch to *Texture Paint* mode, select the first brush (*Draw*), create a new texture under *Tool > Brush Settings > Texture*, choose *Mapping > Stencil*, load your texture in the *Texture* panel:

[image]

To move, scale or rotate the stencil brush use <kbd>RMB</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>, then <kbd>LMB</kbd> to paint:

[image]

At the end don't forget to save or pack the image texture of your material.